# Is there a solution to importing using Appscript

Tags: xcode, compiler-errors

So I have been creating a Appscript which would create a extension on the "finder bar". This extension is called "import CSV data" and if you click it, it will allow you to upload a CSV from your drive or by URL. The code is running, and the script DOES upload data into the sheet, however instead of importing what I have in another sheet to the destination sheet, it imports gibberish errors. For examples, I may have 3 columns of letters "A,B,C". When I run the import, instead of importing "A,B,C" to the destination file,  it uploads something likes this: (%PDF-1.4% ����30obj<</Type/Catalog/Names<<>>/PageLabels<</Nums[0<</S/D/St1)

Does anyone know how to fix this issue? thanks!